# C# regexoptions.ignorecase doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, regex

Using the following code:

```
string pat = @"ENGL101_.*_(.*)";
Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Matches: 
  ENGL101_BELIEVE_WRIGHTSTONE.docx

but not:
  Engl101_ThisIBelieve_Williams.docx

IgnoreCase is on-- what's the issue??

Comment: Dont see any issue with this. It works for me.
What does your code that does the match look like?

Comment: And it's really `Engl` and not `EngI`; `101` and not `1O1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't repro - tried in Snippet Compiler and:

```
    public static void RunSnippet()
    {
        string pat = @"ENGL101_.*_(.*)";
        Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        Match m = r.Match("ENGL101_BELIEVE_WRIGHTSTONE.docx");

        WL(m.Success);

        m = r.Match("Engl101_ThisIBelieve_Williams.docx");

        WL(m.Success);
    }
```

Returns

```
True  
True
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't replicate this problem; both the strings appear to match the expression.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    string pat = @"ENGL101_.*_(.*)";
    Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch(@"ENGL101_BELIEVE_WRIGHTSTONE.docx"));
    Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch(@"Engl101_ThisIBelieve_Williams.docx"));
}
```

**Output:**

```
True
True
```

The problem must be something else, perhaps?

Comment: I agree. Works fine for me using Match and Replace.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may sound obvious, but have you tried matching against

> ENGl101_THISIBELIEVE_WILLIAMOS.docx

without ignore case?